# Remove element slice of struct pointers

Tags: go

I have an application with a recent addition that requires the removal of a struct pointer from a slice that is itself an element of another struct. [A summary of the usage](https://play.golang.org/p/gSHzMdpJTr).

I am wondering if this is idiomatic and okay usage of the go languages. Things appear to work and this appears to be inline with the golang recommendations for [slice element deletion](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)


const ARBITRARY= 5


type myData struct {
    det detailSlicePtr 
}

type detail struct {
    id   int
    name string
}

// Slice of pointers to details
type detailSlicePtr []*detail


// Returns true if item removed succesfully,
// false all other cases
func(s *myData ) remove(d *detail) bool {
    for i:= range s.det {
        if s.det[i].name == d.name && s.det[i].id == d.id {
            s.det[i] = new(detail)
            s.det = append(s.det[:i],s.det[i+1:]...)
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

// Find and remove a struct element from a slice of struct pointers within a     struct
func main() {

    var d myData
    details := make(detailSlicePtr , ARBITRARY)

    for j := 0; j < ARBITRARY; j++ {
        details [j] = &detail{
            id:   j,
            name: strconv.Itoa(j),
        }
    }

    d.det = details 

    // Print out what we have so far
    for index := range d.det {
        fmt.Printf("Item %d is %s\n", index, d.det[index].name)
    }

    findMe := ARBITRARY / 2
    middle := &detail{id: findMe ,name:strconv.Itoa(findMe)}

    if ok := d.remove(middle); !ok {

        fmt.Printf("Unable to find element: %v\n", middle)

    } else {

        fmt.Printf("Found and removed element: %v\n", middle)

        // Print what is left
         for index := range d.det {
            fmt.Printf("Item %d is %s\n", index, d.det[index].name)
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not idiomatic and it is not okay usage. It should be:

> [SliceTricks](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks)
>
> Delete (pointers)
>
> ```
> copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])
> a[len(a)-1] = nil // or the zero value of T
> a = a[:len(a)-1]
> ```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

const ARBITRARY = 5

type myData struct {
    det detailSlicePtr
}

type detail struct {
    id   int
    name string
}

// Slice of pointers to details
type detailSlicePtr []*detail

// Returns true if item removed succesfully,
// false all other cases
func (s *myData) remove(d *detail) bool {
    for i := range s.det {
        if s.det[i].name == d.name && s.det[i].id == d.id {
            copy(s.det[i:], s.det[i+1:])
            s.det[len(s.det)-1] = nil
            s.det = s.det[:len(s.det)-1]
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Find and remove a struct element from a slice of struct pointers within a     struct
func main() {

    var d myData
    details := make(detailSlicePtr, ARBITRARY)

    for j := 0; j < ARBITRARY; j++ {
        details[j] = &detail{
            id:   j,
            name: strconv.Itoa(j),
        }
    }

    d.det = details

    // Print out what we have so far
    for index := range d.det {
        fmt.Printf("Item %d is %s\n", index, d.det[index].name)
    }
    // Print what is hidden
    for i := range d.det[len(d.det):cap(d.det)] {
        j := len(d.det) + i
        det := d.det[:cap(d.det)]
        fmt.Printf("Hidden item %d is %v\n", j, det[j])
    }

    findMe := ARBITRARY / 2
    middle := &detail{id: findMe, name: strconv.Itoa(findMe)}

    if ok := d.remove(middle); !ok {

        fmt.Printf("Unable to find element: %v\n", middle)

    } else {

        fmt.Printf("Found and removed element: %v\n", middle)

        // Print what is left
        for index := range d.det {
            fmt.Printf("Item %d is %s\n", index, d.det[index].name)
        }
        // Print what is hidden
        for i := range d.det[len(d.det):cap(d.det)] {
            j := len(d.det) + i
            det := d.det[:cap(d.det)]
            fmt.Printf("Hidden item %d is %v\n", j, det[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item 0 is 0
Item 1 is 1
Item 2 is 2
Item 3 is 3
Item 4 is 4
Found and removed element: &{2 2}
Item 0 is 0
Item 1 is 1
Item 2 is 3
Item 3 is 4
Hidden item 4 is <nil>
```

**NOTE:** There is a bug in the Slice Tricks that you linked to. It will be corrected soon. Until then use the link in my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So  just to check my understanding:

In the remove method, use copy to basically push our element to the end, nil that index, assign our struct field to the new slice that is now 1 element shorter. 

So this frees the memory consumed by the target element, and shrinks our slice by 1, correct?

I'm not sure how the show hidden loop is not causing a panic here.